# What Triggers the ValueUpdated property in BLE C# code

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building a `Xamarin.Forms`cross platform mobile app, which uses [`Monkey.Robotics`](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Getting%20Started/Mobile_Stack) for its Bluetoth Low Energy functionality. I am connecting to an `mbed` based implimentation of a [custom GATT service](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_GATT_Example/).

In the Xamarin C#, What triggers the Characteristic `ValueUpdated` event in Monkey.Robotics?

This is a standard example my C# is based on:

```
if (characteristic.CanUpdate) {
                characteristic.ValueUpdated += (s, e) => {
                    Debug.WriteLine("characteristic.ValueUpdated");
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
                        UpdateDisplay(characteristic);
                    });
                    IsBusy = false; // only spin until the first result is received
                };
                IsBusy = true;
                characteristic.StartUpdates();
            }
```

This has been working, but since I changed to my own custom GATT service which I am connecting to, the ValueUpdated event is never triggered. What is this event and how is it triggered? Is this a property read from the Characteristic, as set up by the mbed device, or is it something which the mobile end works out?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to ask the author of `Monkey.Robotics`. Assuming it's open-source, you could just look at the code yourself. You should make sure it's calling `WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync()` to enable notifications as a start, and that it has subscribed to the `GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged` event to receive notifications. Please note that `ValueUpdated` is not a property, but rather an _event_. The two are very different.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question, you are quite right, and I have changed the references to an event. The plugin is indeed open source, and the question has a link to the github page. However, I have not been able to find the code that describes this event.

Answer (score 0):

this is from the Android [implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/blob/f6a878571a68ca5a324def55f1d62c1dd48463e8/Source/Platform%20Stacks/Robotics.Mobile.Core.Droid/Bluetooth/LE/Characteristic.cs)

```
    this._gattCallback.CharacteristicValueUpdated += (object sender, CharacteristicReadEventArgs e) => {
            // it may be other characteristics, so we need to test
            if(e.Characteristic.ID == this.ID) {
                // update our underlying characteristic (this one will have a value)
                //TODO: is this necessary? probably the underlying reference is the same.
                //this._nativeCharacteristic = e.Characteristic;

                this.ValueUpdated (this, e);
            }
        };
```

Comment: So does that mean the ValueUpdate event is triggered on the Characteristic.ID changing?

Comment: no, it is fired when the CharacteristicValueUpdated event on the GattCallback class is fired

Comment: hmmm, and is that something which is broadcast by the transmitter, or does the mobile (as the retriever), compare values to historic ones, to work this out?

Comment: Read the code.  I'd guess it's the transmitter, but I don't know anything about GATT